# Direct Deposit From Employer To BitPay?

Tags: bitpay, salary

I searched the site to see if this had been asked and don't see it.  A friend of mine told me yesterday that I could have a portion of my direct deposit directed to a BitPay account that could auto-buy a portion of a bitcoin (like $20 each check).  I searched their site and I couldn't find the routing/account number combination that would be required.

Is this correct and (or) how would someone who's looking to put a small amount of money toward bitcoin each check do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of BitPay providing that service.

The most well known company that specializes in what you describe is BitWage:

https://www.bitwage.com/

Maybe that is what your friend meant since they have similar names,

Answer (score 0):

BitPay offers direct deposit, but it is for their prepaid debit card. As far as I can tell, the funds are in USD and can not be converted into Bitcoin.